# How to modify each element of a block by "foreach" in red/rebol

Tags: rebol, red

I want to modify each element of a block by `foreach`. I tried like this but failed:

```
>> a: [3 4 5 6]
== [3 4 5 6]
>> foreach i a [i + 1]
== 7
>> a
== [3 4 5 6] ;; block a is not changed. What I want is [4 5 6 7]
```

Is there a better way to achieve it?

Comment: Here is another solution using parse: `parse block [some [pos: integer! (change pos pos/1 + 1)]]` or `parse block [some [change v: integer! (v/1 + 1)]]` (latter is Red only)

Comment: Good idea! Thank you @endo64!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes that you made to values do not persist in a block itself. This ties back to your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66793343/how-does-functions-of-red-rebol-pass-parameters-by-value-or-by-reference) about call-by-value parameter passing in Rebol and Red: you modify a *copy* on the stack (passed down to `+` along with `1`), not the actual value slot that sits inside block `a`.

To achieve what you want, you need to increment integers in-place, without pushing them on the stack. One way to do so is by using `forall`.

```
>> block: [1 2 3]
== [1 2 3]
>> also block forall block [block/1: block/1 + 1]
== [2 3 4]
```

What `forall` does is setting a word to a series and then incrementally bumping its index:

```
>> forall block [probe block]
[1 2 3]
[2 3]
[3]
```

Since it doesn't extract the actual values, you can access them using path notation, and then modify them in place. `block/1` always pick the first value on each iteration.

Comment: Thank you. In your example, the function `also` returns `block` that has been modified( [1 2 3] to [2 3 4]), why in the following example, it return the original value? `i:1 also i i: i + 1`, return 1 not 2

Comment: @lyl, arguments to functions are evaluated from left to right, so the first `i` evaluates to `1` before increment happens. `also` evaluates both of its arguments, but returns the first one. In case of a block it is different because what gets modified is a buffer shared between two value slots.

Answer (score 1):

```
>> help forall
USAGE:
   FORALL 'word body

DESCRIPTION: 
   Evaluates body for all values in a series. 
   FORALL is a native! value.

ARGUMENTS:
   'word        [word!] "Word referring to series to iterate over."
   body         [block!]
```

use forall

```
> a: [3 4 5 6]
== [3 4 5 6]
>> forall a [a/1: a/1 + 1]
== 7
>> probe a
[4 5 6 7]
== [4 5 6 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

As usual, no reply with your foreach.

```
a: [2 3 4 5]
b: copy []
foreach i a [append b i + 1]
```

and if you wish you can set a to b now

```
a: b
```

The problem with doing this in one step is that you do not have an index you can use here (despite the suggestive letter i, but that is representing the content of each item inside the block).

So now you can choose your favourite solution.

Comment: Another good solution! Thank you. And why must `copy` be used for `b`? What' wrong with simply `b: []`?

Comment: That is a good question and it brings you closer to understanding Rebol. Because in Rebol code is data (and data can thus also be code) if you have a script and say b: [] then that is code that (in C terms) assigns a pointer called b to that particular piece of code represented by the []. So if that changes because you say c: b and then change c, b also changes, it points to the same initial []. To do a copy makes sure it copies a new empty block [].