# Value of local variables in a function seems not be released post function calling in Red/Rebol language

Tags: rebol, red, rebol3, rebol2

I construct a function named `find-all` to find all indexes of a given item in a series by "recursive".
The first calling of `find-all` gives the right output. However from the second calling, all outputs are appended together.

```
find-all: function [series found][
result: [] 
  either any [empty? series none? s-found: find series found]
     [result]
     [append result index? s-found
      find-all next s-found found]
]

;; test:
probe find-all "abcbd" "b"   ;; output [2 4] as expected
probe find-all [1 2 3 2 1] 2  ;; output [2 4 2 4]
```

Since variables inside a function created with `function` are local, why does the value of variable `result` is still there during later funtion callings, which cause the `result` of the sencond calling of `find-all` does not begin with `[]`?
And what is the correct recursive way to achieve this funciton?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is evident if you inspect `find-all` after making these two calls:

```
>> ?? find-all
find-all: func [series found /local result s-found][
    result: [2 4 2 4] 
    either any [empty? series none? s-found: find series found] 
    [result] 
    [append result index? s-found 
        find-all next s-found found
    ]
]
```

`result` is an [indirect value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66793343/how-does-functions-of-red-rebol-pass-parameters-by-value-or-by-reference), and its data buffer is stored on a heap. The data gets preserved between the calls and accumulated, because you do not re-create it with `copy` — `result` being local to function's context is unrelated to that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @9214's help, especially the description about `indirect value`. I give a solution like this:

```
find-all: function [series found][
  either any [empty? series none? s-found: find series found]
     [[]]
     [append
        reduce [index? s-found]
        find-all next s-found found
    ]
]

;; test:
probe find-all "abcbd" "b"   ;; output [2 4] as expected
probe find-all [1 2 3 2 1] 2  ;; output [2 4] as expected
```